# How can I determine spatial resolution from an Airy disk diffraction pattern?

Tags: optics, imaging

From introductory optics, the angular resolution of a lens (in radians) can be described by the Rayleigh criterion:

\begin{align*}
\theta = 1.220 \frac{\lambda}{d}
\end{align*}

This has its parallel with the spatial resolution equation

\begin{align*}
\Delta l = 1.220 f\frac{\lambda}{d}
\end{align*}

where $f$ is the focal length of the lens, $\lambda$ is the wavelength of light and $d$ is the diameter of the lens.

I tried to test this by building my own imaging system. I shined laser light through a $1 \mu$m pinhole and recorded the diffraction pattern by placing a camera at the imaging plane.

I am using a lens that has a diameter of 50 mm and a focal length of 40 mm. The wavelength of light that I am using is 780 nm. This gives a theoretical spatial resolution of about 750 nm. That means that in an ideal experiment I could tell apart two points as long as they are at least 750 nm apart. At closer distances, their diffraction patterns would make them indistinguishable from each other.

Here is a picture I took of a 1 $\mu$m pinhole at 25 times magnification:

[image: An image of a 1 micron pinhole I took at 25x magnification.]

This pinhole image has a full width at half maximum of about 50 $\mu$m. I would have expected this to be around 25 $\mu$m because the pinhole is 1 $\mu$m and the magnification is 25 times.

How can I check the theoretical calculation from the information that I have? Does the 50 $\mu$m FWHM mean that my spatial resolution is 2 $\mu$m because I got double what I expected for a 1 $\mu$m pinhole?

Unfortunately, I do not have the means to take two 1 $\mu$m pinholes and spatially separate them by 750 nm to check and see if they are distinguishable. ;)